# How can I run a cron job every 5 minutes starting from a time other than 0 minutes?

Tags: unix, cron

I would like to have a script run every 5 minutes let's say starting from 13:02 so I can have another script runs every 5 minutes but starting from 13:04 so the second script runs two minutes after the start of the first job. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

#### Syntax 1

```
*/5+2 * * * * 1st-script
*/5+4 * * * * 2nd-script
```

For future reference take a look at this online [Cron Job Generator](https://www.generateit.net/cron-job/).

#### Syntax 2

Since there are several reports that the `+` syntax is not working on Ubuntu 14.04, here's a variation:

```
2-59/5 * * * * 1st-script
4-59/5 * * * * 2nd-script
```

This will result in the 1st script to run every 5 minutes starting with an offset of 2 minutes at the beginning of each hour and the 2nd script to behave the same with an offset of 4 minutes.

Comment: Which version of cron are you using that supports this syntax? Cronie doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: Debian based linux distributions support this syntax, check out this list: https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I should be looking for on that page. The word "cron" isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: You asked for version and I pointed out Debian based linux distros where this syntax works. Here's a links to the cron package from Debian's latest version: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/cron. Not really sure if this will help you though.

Comment: @xtian Yes I seem to have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Did you find another fix?

Comment: I finally used a variation of the "sleep trick" by Emile Aben below

Comment: @xtian, please take a look at the alternative solution I've added and let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: My cPanel (version 11.52) doesn't seem to accept none of those syntaxes. I've solved with 1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * * php ...

Comment: Same issue in Ubuntu 16.04. The original answer doesn't work but the updated version does

Comment: The cron in RHEL 6.10 doesn't like `*/5+2` either, but `2-59/5` works like a champ.

Comment: The updated version with `2-59/5` is needed for Firebase scheduled functions too. tnx

Comment: Little note for thos who are interested: only the second syntax is valid for github actions workflows scheduling

Answer (score 15):

or

```
*/5 * * * * sleep 120; ( first_script.sh & ) ; sleep 120 ; second_script.sh
```

nice thing about this approach is that you can let crontab start things at times other then minute boundaries (like 30 seconds after the hour)

Answer (score 6):

```
*/5+1 * * * * first_script.sh
```

To run every five minutes, but offset one minute

Answer (score 6):

I needed similar thing - to execute script every 5 minutes starting from third minute of an hour. I doubted above solutions (because website crontab.guru was convincing me about invalid syntax) and so my colleague told me to specify minutes directly like this:

3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,43,48,53,58 * * * *

Its list of concrete minutes.