# How to write bash script that autoruns every 10 min?

Tags: bash, cron

I've been working on a project and I would so not like it to be taken by system crash.

So I wrote a script to backup my whole project directory into Dropbox.

But I had to run it every 10 min, if I could remember to do that.

Question: any way to auto-it-up?

Comment: Just use cron to run every 10 minutes

Comment: Have you tried cron jobs?

Comment: take a look [here](https://support.asperasoft.com/entries/20150712-How-to-run-a-cron-job-every-5-minutes)

Comment: Suggestions for [tag:cron] are all well and good, but why not work in a directory that is sync'd with Dropbox? https://www.dropbox.com/help/4/en

Comment: I feel so stupid as not even know about crontab, such a great tool. Thanks guys.

Comment: Working in a sync'd directory makes me feel like being exposed and insecure LOL.

Comment: LOL? How is this more exposed and less secure than uploading via a hand-rolled Bash script and Cron?

Comment: you can use cron,,I put the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type the following command to enter cronjob:

```
$ crontab -e
```

To get crontab to run a task every 10 minutes you could type as follow:

```
*/10 * * * * /path_to_script
```

See additional read for it:

[**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab)

[**cron-every-5-minutes**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/)

**[cron job every 5 minutes starting from a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094545/cron-job-every-5-minutes-starting-from-a-specific-time)**

Answer (score 2):

try this solution:

```
cat cronjob
*/10 * * * * sh /path/to/scipt.sh
```

Then:

```
chmod +x /path/to/scipt.sh
chmod +x cronjob    
/etc/init.d/crond start  #redhat based servers like centos
/etc/init.d/cron  start  #debian based servers like ubuntu

crontab cronjob
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is by crontab, as others suggest. Here is another solution, by adding only one line to your backup-script.

If your system has installed and enabled the "at" suite, see:

- [man atd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man8/atd.8.html)
- [man at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/at.1.html)
- or [atrun](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atrun&sektion=8) if you using bsd like system

you can simply queue the "next run-time" from your backup script. So, for example, if your backup script is called `/home/joe/bin/copy_to_dropbox`, add to the end of script the next line:

```
af -f /home/joe/bin/copy_to_dropbox now +10 minute
```

and run manually the backup script first time.

After the first backup, the `at` command in the script queues itself for the next execution.

You can check the `at queue` with the "atq" command.

Comment: very detailed answer, appreciated:)