# Set a 2 cron jobs that runs every 10 minutes but don't run on top of each other

Tags: cron, server

I can setup a cron every ten minutes like this:

```
*/10 * * * *
```

But I want to setup 2 cron jobs that won't run at the same time.

Is it possible to make one run every 10 minutes like this:

```
12.00, 12.10, 12.20, 12.30, 12.40...
```

And the other run:

```
12.05, 12.15, 12.25, 12.35, 12.45...
```

So both runs every 10 minutes, just not at the exact same time if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule them to start 5 minutes apart with a 10 minute cycle.

To run every 10 minutes starting at whole hours you can use;

```
0/10 * * * *
```

...for [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50](http://crontab.guru/#0/10_*_*_*_*).

To run every 10 minutes starting at 5 past every hour;

```
5/10 * * * *
```

...for [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55](http://crontab.guru/#5/10_*_*_*_*).

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate : [How can I run a cron job every 5 minutes starting from a time other than 0 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094545/how-can-i-run-a-cron-job-every-5-minutes-starting-from-a-time-other-than-0-minut)

You can look at first answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16094616/1079254

Another simple solution is listing all minutes you want separated by commas :

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * *
```

I think this syntax is more understandable for humans and it should be available in every cron software.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a 5m cronjob with a Script who switch from one to another in every execution?

It's what I would do **if possible**. Good luck!