# Want to run cron every 5 minute but the code in cron sholud execute at 4m 30s

Tags: cron

I want to run cron job on every 5 minute but cron code should be run at 4 minutes and 30 seconds.

What I want to Do - I have online questions paper in which students have to answer in first 4.30 minutes. in next 30 second I want to calculate the results via cron job. So the cron will hit after 4.30 minute.

or

first cron run at 1pm 04minute
then sleep 1 minute
total = 1pm 04 minute + 1 minute(sleep time) = 1pm 5minute

new session at 1pm 5minute

and repeat

This task repeats for 3 hours.

Comment: "I want to run cron job on every 5 minute but cron code should be run at 4 minutes and 30 seconds"...this sounds like a contradiction. Please make your requirement clearer.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, Actually I have to run the cron job of 5 minute interval and this  5 minute interval should like this -  4m.30s , 9m.30s, 14m.30s, 19m.30s like so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094545/how-can-i-run-a-cron-job-every-5-minutes-starting-from-a-time-other-than-0-minut might help you